# Text not showing when calling a Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a Form which just accepts a number and a text for displaying a ProgressBar. I initialize and show the Form this way:

```
Dim progressForm = New DisplayProgressForm 
progressForm.Show()
```

However, the Labels don't display but the ProgressBar works properly.
If I call the Form, say, with `progressForm.ShowDialog()` the display is ok.  What am I missing?  I call the progress form from a class and no multi-threading code used.

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Reflection.Emit
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class DisplayProgressForm

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Public Sub InitializeDisplay(description As String, nMaxValue As Int32)
        lblDescription.Text = description
        ProgressBar.Maximum = nMaxValue
        ProgressBar.Value = 0
    End Sub

    Public Sub DisplayProgress(count As Int32)
        ProgressBar.Maximum = count
    End Sub

    Public Sub UpdateProgressBar(counter As Int32)
        ProgressBar.Value = counter
        Dim percent As Decimal = (counter / ProgressBar.Maximum * 100)
        lblPercentage.Text = percent.ToString() + "%"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Designer file:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class DisplayProgressForm
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.ProgressBar = New System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar()
        Me.lblDescription = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.lblPercentage = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.SuspendLayout
        '
        'ProgressBar
        '
        Me.ProgressBar.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 33)
        Me.ProgressBar.Name = "ProgressBar"
        Me.ProgressBar.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(681, 23)
        Me.ProgressBar.TabIndex = 0
        '
        'lblDescription
        '
        Me.lblDescription.AutoSize = true
        Me.lblDescription.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent
        Me.lblDescription.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Popup
        Me.lblDescription.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
        Me.lblDescription.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(13, 14)
        Me.lblDescription.Name = "lblDescription"
        Me.lblDescription.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(182, 17)
        Me.lblDescription.TabIndex = 1
        Me.lblDescription.Text = "Please Wait Processing Request...."
        Me.lblDescription.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true
        '
        'lblPercentage
        '
        Me.lblPercentage.AutoSize = true
        Me.lblPercentage.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCoral
        Me.lblPercentage.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 59)
        Me.lblPercentage.Name = "lblPercentage"
        Me.lblPercentage.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(121, 13)
        Me.lblPercentage.TabIndex = 2
        Me.lblPercentage.Text = "Percentage Processed :"
        '
        'DisplayProgressForm
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6!, 13!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Info
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(705, 131)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblPercentage)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblDescription)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.ProgressBar)
        Me.DoubleBuffered = true
        Me.KeyPreview = true
        Me.Name = "DisplayProgressForm"
        Me.Text = "Form1"
        Me.ResumeLayout(false)
        Me.PerformLayout
    End Sub

    Private WithEvents ProgressBar As Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
    Private WithEvents lblPercentage As Windows.Forms.Label
    Private WithEvents lblDescription As Windows.Forms.Label
End Class
```

Public Class AccountReconPresenter

```
Private Sub UpdateTotals()
        If View.AccountIdNo > 0 And View.ReconciliationDate IsNot Nothing Then
            View.TotalDebitsCleared = 0
            View.TotalCreditsCleared = 0
            View.TotalDebitsNotCleared = 0
            View.TotalCreditsNotCleared = 0
            View.TotalQtyDebitsCleared = 0
            View.TotalQtyCreditsCleared = 0
            View.TotalQtyDebitsNotCleared = 0
            View.TotalQtyCreditsNotCleared = 0
            Dim progressDisplayForm = New CBaseControlsLibrary.DisplayProgressForm
            progressDisplayForm.Show()
            Dim nCount = View.AccountReconciliationItems.Count()
            progressDisplayForm.DisplayProgress(nCount)
            progressDisplayForm.InitializeDisplay("Please wait computing reconciliation totals...", nCount)
            Dim counter As Int32 = 1
            For Each accountReconciliationItem In View.AccountReconciliationItems
                If accountReconciliationItem.Cleared Then
                    If accountReconciliationItem.Debit > 0 Then
                        View.TotalDebitsCleared += accountReconciliationItem.Debit
                        View.TotalQtyDebitsCleared += 1
                    Else
                        View.TotalCreditsCleared += accountReconciliationItem.Credit
                        View.TotalQtyCreditsCleared += 1
                    End If
                Else
                    If accountReconciliationItem.Debit > 0 Then
                        View.TotalDebitsNotCleared += accountReconciliationItem.Debit
                        View.TotalQtyDebitsNotCleared += 1
                    Else
                        View.TotalCreditsNotCleared += accountReconciliationItem.Credit
                        View.TotalQtyCreditsNotCleared += 1
                    End If
                End If
                progressDisplayForm.UpdateProgressBar(counter)
                counter = counter + 1
            Next
            progressDisplayForm.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

End class

[image]

Comment: You need to show when and where you create a new Instance of this Form, when / where your methods: `InitializeDisplay`, `DisplayProgress` and `UpdateProgressBar` are called, what code calls them. -- Are you initializing this Form from a Thread other than the UI Thread?

Comment: You are almost certainly doing everything on the UI thread. You need to either create and display the progress form on a secondary thread or do the work on a secondary thread. Either way, if you want to affect the form from the code doing the work, you'll need to marshal a method call to the correct thread to update the UI. Instead, I suggest that you use [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?869567).

Comment: There is no multi-threading everything is called on the UI Thread.  I call this progress bar form from a class not from a form.